# Solution to run another program with arguments specified in static configuration file?

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there ready made solution to run program (*let's call that `launcher.exe`*) with `.exe` file extension (*extension is important*) that looks for static configuration file, for example *`launcher.cfg`*, and launches another program specified within configuration file.

Or maybe `launcher.exe` that will execute `launcher.cmd` or some other script that can be used to pass control forward.

Another explanation of requirements if that is not already clear enough:

***1.*** User or some other program launches `program.exe`
***2.*** `program.exe` launches `program.cmd` which is shell script executed by `cmd.exe`

Important thing is that `launcher.exe` is program with `.exe` file extension and it does not need any command line arguments to launch another script or program with command line arguments.

Comment: May I ask why? This is a fairly trivial task in most major programming languages, but I don't see the purpose. You want to run a executable with extension `.exe` that launches a `.bat`?

Comment: @Bob Yes, that behavior is needed when replacing parts of application that consists of many .exe files that are launcher by application's controller module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any *ready made* program that does this.

I had a bit of spare time, so here's a quick C++ program.

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

#define COMMAND_PRE "call "
#define COMMAND_POST ".bat"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char command[strlen(COMMAND_PRE) + strlen(argv[0]) + strlen(COMMAND_POST) + 1];

    strcpy(command, COMMAND_PRE);
    strcat(command, argv[0]);
    strcat(command, COMMAND_POST);

    printf("Running \"%s\"", command);
    system(command);

    system("pause");
}
```

Of course, Norton was nice enough to call it high risk because of the `system(command);` line, which just executes a `.bat` file. Whatever, I can't be bothered trying to find an antivirus-safe method (and Norton's "SONAR" protection overreacts quite often).

Name the program `whatever.exe` and it'll run the file `whatever.exe.bat`. In other words, it'll take its own filename (and path), append `.bat` to the end, and run it.

You can compile it yourself from the above source. I'll also provide a download link to the compiled program [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?25nlir1k2be75wm), but use at your own risk - no one here is responsible for what may happen

Comment: +1 This answer is good enough and i've already thought that i may need to `make` one for that purpose. I was just lazy in setting up dev env to virtualbox which is my only winmachine and thought if someone already knows some solution for that... actually application that uses many `.exe` files is windows :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found alternate solution for this which I think is not as good as Bob's answer.

However, it is working solution and I'll post it for future reference:

`.cmd` and `.bat` files can be compiled to `.exe` files (*with some limitations*) with `batch compiler` found at [sf.net/projects/batchcompiler](http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/batchcompiler/).

This way one can write batch file

```
start anotherbatch.cmd /arg1 /arg2
```

And compile that to `batchfile.exe`

Comment: Assuming the limitations you mentioned don't include this, you can mimic my program: `echo Running "%0.bat"` followed by `call %0.bat` followed by `pause` should do exactly the same thing.

Comment: @Bob This is one of limitations i mentioned, at least with compiler i linked, it will not expand `%0` at runtime but save it as constant value while compiling so compiled program will not behave exactly as original batch file.